# Duplicate class com.google.android.flexbox - Android Admob

Tags: android, admob, facebook-ads

I am using admob and facebook for ads in my app and its done but I want to check it so i have added Mediation Test Suite depnedancy

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0'
```

And the app could not build it shows

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.flexbox.AlignContent found in modules jetified-flexbox-1.1.1-runtime (com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1) and jetified-flexbox-3.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.flexbox.AlignItems found in modules jetified-flexbox-1.1.1-runtime (com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1) and jetified-flexbox-3.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0)
```

And many more Duplicate Class of Flexbox

my admob version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Osman I did not solve the problem yet

Comment: In my case It was problem for adding flexbox into gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name is wrong.

```
com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1
```

Here is the correct one. ↓

```
implementation ('com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0') {
   exclude group: "com.google.android", module: "flexbox"
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the flexbox module which is causing the conflict like this...

```
implementation ('com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0') {
   exclude group: "com.google.android.flexbox", module: "flexbox"
}
```